# Is Build required for uploading to appstore

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, application-loader

I am ready to upload my app to appStore. I read this http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-create-app-on-app-store.html

But this article says after creating everything choose archive, Is Build is required before click Archive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**

When you click Archive it will build and create new ipa file. Than you will have to submit the application from the archievs screen. See screenshot for more information

[image]

Comment: I followed above site. That site used product name under project>buildsettings. Is it need?

Comment: Procedure is like you will set appropriate mobile provisioning profiles in project settings. Than Archieve the project, you will be redirected to above screen and than you can distribute from there. Steps are simple enough to follow, feel free to ask if you need more help.

Comment: 1.I create app id, bundle id. 2.And set my bundle id to xcode bundle identifier like com.sss.com.  3. Then i go to provisioning profile page click Distribution tab. Create new profile for App store. Download this profile to xcode. 4. Set Code signing in distribution only? 5. In edit scheme Build Configuration is Distribution. 6. clean and Archive.......

Comment: Perfect. In latest Xcode when you distribute using wizard it will sense bundle identifier and will bring list of matching certificate to sign it with so you will have to select distribution certificate from there. If you make any mistake it will let you know straight away.

Comment: what should i select in build setting Debug, Release, Distribution. I need to upload for my client. In distribution only use client id?

Comment: You will have to create provisioning profile as I said, for Adhoc and distribution. Please refer [this tutorial series](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1) for more detailed information how to submit application to app store from no account.